# spawning process on erlang cluster

Tags: process, erlang, cluster-computing, spawn

If I spawn a new process on a busy node in an erlang cluster and other nodes are idle will the process automatically be spawned on one of the free nodes?

Update: I found another question similar to this one too:

[Using Erlang, how should I distribute load amongst a cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662131/using-erlang-how-should-i-distribute-load-amongst-a-cluster)

Comment: interesting info: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/overload.html ... thanks to "whoppix" on #erlang freenode irc.

Comment: So does scaling have to be performed manually then, by checking if a node is overloaded and then sending the call to another node?

Comment: You can distribute the load information of your nodes at certain intervals, and always select the one having the least load for a new process. This will only work though if the distribution interval is fairly shorter than the processes' lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not. Spawning is "not declarative".